# Open CV Watershed not segmenting oval objects properly

Tags: python, opencv, watershed

Attemping to create a way to process images to count different types of tablets. The following code has been working well for circular objects, however oval shapes are creating issues that I cant find a workaround for.

```
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)


image = cv2.imread('sample.jpg')
shifted = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (15, 15), 1)
shifted = cv2.pyrMeanShiftFiltering(shifted, 21, 51)
shifted = cv2.erode(shifted,kernel,iterations=1)
shifted = cv2.dilate(shifted,kernel,iterations=1)
cv2.imwrite("step1.jpg", shifted)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(shifted, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255,
    cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
cv2.imwrite("step2.jpg", thresh)
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh,cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernel, iterations = 2)
cv2.imwrite("step3.jpg", thresh)
thresh = cv2.bitwise_not(thresh)
thresh = cv2.erode(thresh,kernel,iterations=1)
cv2.imwrite("step4.jpg", thresh)
D = ndimage.distance_transform_edt(thresh)
localMax = peak_local_max(D, indices=False, min_distance=10,
    labels=thresh)
markers = ndimage.label(localMax, structure=np.ones((3, 3)))[0]

labels = watershed(-D, markers, mask=thresh)
print("[INFO] {} unique segments found".format(len(np.unique(labels)) - 1))
for label in np.unique(labels):
    if label == 0:
        continue
    mask = np.zeros(gray.shape, dtype="uint8")
    mask[labels == label] = 255
    cnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
    c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
    ((x, y), r) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
    cv2.circle(image, (int(x), int(y)), int(r), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.putText(image, "#{}".format(label), (int(x) - 10, int(y)),
        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.6, (0, 0, 255), 2)
cv2.imwrite("step5.jpg", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Image that is being used is :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zm8nm.jpg

Output after filtering yields :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bj8Qz.jpg

Any teaching points as to how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest you fit your contours to ellipses rather than using circles.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a better way to use the watershed operator.

It relies on having a good gradient, but if the images are similar to this one, you should be able to do this effectively. Also, there are very powerful edge detectors today, much better than the one I used on this demo.

```py
import cv2 
import numpy as np
import higra as hg
from skimage.segmentation import relabel_sequential
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

def main():                                                                                                                                                                                             
    img_path = "pills.jpg"                                                                                                                                                                              
    img = cv2.imread(img_path)                                                                                                                                                                          
    img = cv2.resize(img, (256, 256))                                                                                                                                                                   
    img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (9, 9), 0)                                                                                                                                                              

    edges = cv2.Canny(img, 100, 100)                                                                                                                                                                    

    size = img.shape[:2]                                                                                                                                                                                
    graph = hg.get_4_adjacency_graph(size)                                                                                                                                                              
    edge_weights = hg.weight_graph(graph, edges, hg.WeightFunction.mean)                                                                                                                                

    tree, altitudes = hg.watershed_hierarchy_by_area(graph, edge_weights)                                                                                                                               
    segments = hg.labelisation_horizontal_cut_from_threshold(tree, altitudes, 500)                                                                                                                      
    segments, _, _ = relabel_sequential(segments)                                                                                                                                                       
    print('The number of pills is ', segments.max() - 1)                                                                                                                                                
    plt.imshow(segments)                                                                                                                                                                                
    plt.show()                                                                                                                                                                                          

if __name__ == "__main__":                                                                                                                                                                              
    main()
```

Initially, I resize the image to speed up the computation and apply a blur to reduce the background gradient. I detect its edges (gradient) and create a graph with it as edge weights; then I compute the watershed hierarchy ordered by area and threshold it obtaining the connected component at that level, from this you can count the number of segments.

[image: Segmentation result]